# Weird graphical glitch in Firefox. But only lasts for about half a second

Tags: graphics, firefox, amd-graphics

I sometimes see these graphical glitches, only in Firefox, when clicking on some sort of menu.
It's only on screen for about half a second (or less) and then the glitch disappears and the menu looks normal.
I'm running latest instance of Ubuntu 20.04 and the latest instance of FF but this occurred in earlier builds of FF as well.  Wayland, Gnome desktop. I'm running an AMD GPU, stock AMD drivers that ship/install with Ubuntu installation.

I don't see this glitch all the time and I've never seen it in other applications. Has anyone else seen this in Firefox or knows what may be the cause/resolution?

I've never used Firefox before but because of vaapi support I'm using it more often these days than other browsers.

I've included a photo which illustrates what I'm seeing.  The image on the left is what a Firefox menu item might look like for a second before the 'glitch' disappears and the menu item looks normal.

[image]

Comment: Try the 5.8 kernel. It can be installed by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`. It has better support of AMD GPUs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  If kernel 5.8 is the fix I might way until it's officially supported in 20.04 LTS as I don't want to lose LivePatch support.

Comment: Maybe try the default theme?

Comment: Interesting suggestion, I actually am using the Default firefox theme.  However, I had dark mode enabled for Ubuntu. I've changed the Ubuntu theme to standard.  I've kept the firefox theme to default to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm also still encountering this on latest Ubuntu 20.04 with the 5.8 hwe kernel on X with AMD RX 5700.

Comment: Yes, I also ended up moving to 5.8 hwe kernel and unfortunately that didn't resolve the problem.  It's not like this is a major problem, I just find it a bit odd and I've only seen Firefox exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Yeah, same here, thought my GPU was reaching the end of its life, a bit relieved that someone else has the same issue.